# How do I get facet data from a plotly event in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, r-plotly

I am trying `shiny` including some `plotly` plots. I want to use reactive events, so when I click on the plot another plot gets updated based on filtered data. The thing is that the plot I want to have the click event has facets, and I want to filter the data based on the clicked facet. But as far as I can tell, the facet info is not sent back in the event data.

I simplified the example of [shiny plotly events](https://plot.ly/r/shinyapp-plotly-events/) to include facets (see the reprex below), but none of the events receive the facet info. In particular, the `event_data("plotly_click")` which is the one I am interested in, does not get the clicked facet anywhere.

```
library(plotly)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    plotlyOutput("plot"),
    verbatimTextOutput("hover"),
    verbatimTextOutput("click"),
    verbatimTextOutput("brush"),
    verbatimTextOutput("zoom")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    output$plot <- renderPlotly({
        # use the key aesthetic/argument to help uniquely identify selected observations
        key <- row.names(mtcars)
        p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = wt, colour = factor(vs), key = key)) + 
            geom_point() +
            facet_grid(rows = "gear")
        ggplotly(p) %>% layout(dragmode = "select")
    })


    output$hover <- renderPrint({
        d <- event_data("plotly_hover")
        if (is.null(d)) "Hover events appear here (unhover to clear)" else d
    })

    output$click <- renderPrint({
        d <- event_data("plotly_click")
        if (is.null(d)) "Click events appear here (double-click to clear)" else d
    })

    output$brush <- renderPrint({
        d <- event_data("plotly_selected")
        if (is.null(d)) "Click and drag events (i.e., select/lasso) appear here (double-click to clear)" else d
    })

    output$zoom <- renderPrint({
        d <- event_data("plotly_relayout")
        if (is.null(d)) "Relayout (i.e., zoom) events appear here" else d
    })


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I've been googling it and cannot find a solution. Is there anything I can pass on, for example, to the render function so it does get the facet and can send it bac in the event data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, you can see in the example code you adapted that they "use the key aesthetic/argument to help uniquely identify selected observations". Why don't you use it to identify the facet?

You would only need to tweak one line in your code, changing `key = gear` within `aes()`.